# standard map annotation for iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to display my custom annotations in the map and my current location as the standard pin in the map view with the blue color.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *identifier = @"MapPin";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotations class]]) {
        MyAnnotations *ann= annotation;
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [self.map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            if (ann.custom){
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom.png"];
            }else{
               //?? annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluePin.png?"];
            }
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        if(ann.custom){
            UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationPicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=nextButton;
        }
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `custom` property is to distinguish between your annotations and the map view's user location, that case is already handled by the first `if` which checks the annotation's class and the `custom` property would be unnecessary.

The map view's user location annotation is of type `MKUserLocation` so the code will return `nil` in that case and the map view will show the standard blue dot (assuming `showsUserLocation` is `YES`).

However, if the `custom` property is to distinguish between two types of your *own* annotations, then one problem is that it doesn't handled re-used annotation views properly (when `annotationView != nil`).

When an annotation view is re-used, its `image` and `rightCalloutAccessoryView` may not be right for the current `annotation` so those properties need to be set (or cleared) whether a view is being re-used or not.  For example:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotations class]]) {
    MyAnnotations *ann= annotation;
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [self.map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    //set view properties that depend on annotation-specific properties
    //regardless of whether view is new or re-used...
    if (ann.custom)
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom.png"];

        UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationPicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=nextButton;
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluePin.png"];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

Though if the `custom` property is just to separate *all* your annotations from the map view's user location, it's unnecessary in the first place (as long as you check the annotation's `class` and set `showsUserLocation` to `YES`).

Comment: I treied: else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){
        return nil;
} but clicking on the user location annotation crashes ...

Comment: The code you tried in your comment seems irrelevant to your original question as well as the crash (for which it would be somewhat helpful to have the exact exception message).

Answer (score 0):

may be you put custom code in this event .because when you click on current location annotation this method calls and may be bacause of that code application crashes.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
}
```

Thanks.